# manual binary search wrap up

Tags: ruby, if-statement, recursion, binary-search

Would anyone be so kind to explain to me how I finish my recursive binary search problem?  The recursive aspect is confusing me.  I would love for an explanation on what thats doing if possible!!!  I think I need to increment the 'half' value I have within the if or elsif but I don't know what it would look like.  Please suggest ways to add to the code I currently have rather than refactor to something simpler... at least at first!  Thanks!

```
def binary_search(letter, array)
  half = (array.length - 1)/2
  if letter == array[half]
    return half
  end
  if letter > array[half] && letter <= array[-1]
    array = array[half...array.length]
    binary_search(letter, array)
  elsif letter < array[half] && letter >= array[0]
    array = array[0...half]
    binary_search(letter, array)
  else
    nil
  end
end

arr = [:A, :B, :C, :D, :E, :F, :G]
p binary_search(:C, arr)
```

Comment: Some slightly different takes:  http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Binary_search#Ruby

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`half` was part of the problem. With a `length` of 2, `half` would be `0`, and you would "split" your array in a full array and an empty array : recursion would never end.

You also need to keep an index, and add `half` to it when you consider the 2nd Array :

```
def binary_search(letter, array, i=0)
  puts "Been here for #{array} with #{i}"
  half = array.length / 2
  if letter == array[half]
    return i + half
  end
  if letter > array[half] && letter <= array[-1]
    binary_search(letter, array.drop(half), i + half)
  elsif letter < array[half] && letter >= array[0]
    binary_search(letter, array.take(half), i)
  else
    nil
  end
end

arr = [:A, :B, :C, :D, :E, :F, :G]
p binary_search(:C, arr)
p binary_search(:G, arr)
```

It outputs

```
Been here for [:A, :B, :C, :D, :E, :F, :G] with 0
Been here for [:A, :B, :C] with 0
Been here for [:B, :C] with 1
2
Been here for [:A, :B, :C, :D, :E, :F, :G] with 0
Been here for [:D, :E, :F, :G] with 3
Been here for [:F, :G] with 5
6
```